# Массив в масиве

Tags: php, массивы

Что неправильно в такой конструкции?

```
$ter = array('test-3', 'test-4');

$taxquery = array(
    'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'xtag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $ter
    )   
);
```

Comment: Краткий ответ - в этом вопросе некоректно задан вопрос. Почему именно такой ответ, потому что нет правильного или неправильного, нет плохого или хорошего. Но есть такой код, который не оправдывает Ваши ожидания и такой который оправдывает. (ИМХО)

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно. Можете отступы для красоты расставить :)

```
$ter = array('test-3', 'test-4');
$taxquery = array(
  'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'xtag',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $ter
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

А почему вы решили, что конструкция не работает? Все работает! Скажите, какую операцию у вас не получается сделать.
Код:

```
$ter = array('test-3', 'test-4');
$taxquery = array(
    'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
    'tax_query' => array(
      'taxonomy' => 'xtag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $ter
    )    
);

print_r($taxquery["tax_query"]["terms"]);  
// выводит "Array ( [0] => test-3 [1] => test-4 )".
```

Все верно =)